# How is it possible to add a container for border layout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

I want to add labels and buttons above and below the border layout. How can I do that? Here is what I did:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

class homework{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame= new JFrame("border layout");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JLabel label=new JLabel("Container of BorderLayout");
        JButton button1 = new JButton("NORTH");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("SOUTH");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("EAST");
        JButton button5 = new JButton("CENTER");
        JButton button4 = new JButton("WEST");
        JPanel panel1=new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2=new JPanel();

        frame.add(panel2);
        label.setLayout(new FlowLayout(0));
        panel2.add(label);
        panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel1.add(button1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel1.add(button2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel1.add(button3,BorderLayout.EAST);
        panel1.add(button4,BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel1.add(button5,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(panel1);

        frame.pack();

    }
}
```

Comment: PROTIP: Java and JavaScript are 2 different things.

Comment: Well, what is the problem with what you did? What do you want to happen? What do you mean "above and below"? Perhaps add the way you would like this to look in a picture?

Comment: Nest some JPanels with BorderLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above and below of border layout, set new 2 containers (for example JPanel) and make them flow layout. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXCpM.png)

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JRadioButton rdbtnNewRadioButton = new JRadioButton("New radio button");
    panel.add(rdbtnNewRadioButton);

    JRadioButton rdbtnNewRadioButton_1 = new JRadioButton("New radio button");
    panel.add(rdbtnNewRadioButton_1);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
    panel_1.add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("New label");
    panel_1.add(lblNewLabel_1);
```

add something like that before frame.pack(); code.

Actually what do you mean by above and below? Do you mean north and south? If It is you should have something like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbLJp.png)
and you should write code this way

```
 import java.awt.*;

   class homework{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame= new JFrame("border layout");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JLabel label=new JLabel("Container of BorderLayout");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("EAST");
        JButton button5 = new JButton("CENTER");
        JButton button4 = new JButton("WEST");
        JPanel panel1=new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2=new JPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel2);
        label.setLayout(new FlowLayout(0));
        panel2.add(label);
        panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel1.add(button3,BorderLayout.EAST);
        panel1.add(button4,BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel1.add(button5,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel1);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel1.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
        panel.add(lblNewLabel);

        JRadioButton rdbtnNewRadioButton = new JRadioButton("New radio button");
        panel.add(rdbtnNewRadioButton);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("New label");
        panel_1.add(lblNewLabel_1);

        JRadioButton rdbtnNewRadioButton_1 = new JRadioButton("New radio button");
        panel_1.add(rdbtnNewRadioButton_1);

        frame.pack();

    }
 }
```

In two conditions, you should add two containers into your code and make them flow layout.